# Why does omniauth-oauth2 strategy append /oauth/authorize to my site url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I am using the sample provided by [omniauth-oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2) to create a custom Oauth2 provider. This is fairly easy and I use `option :client_options, {site: "https://sub.dom.is?id=myId"}` for my issuer but when the redirection happens I get a 404 and when I check the URL I can see that is is actually `https://sub.dom.is/oauth/authorize?id=myID` and of course this is wrong since there has been added **oauth/authorize** to the URL..

does anyone know why? or who adds it and then how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [anti-pattern.com](http://anti-pattern.com/adding-a-new-strategy-to-omniauth) ... when I provide only the site the omniauth-oauth2 will add oauth/authorize to it as a default. However, if I provided authorize_url like so option :client_options,{site:"https://www.dom.is",authorize_url:"https://sub.dom.is?id=‌​myID"} the autorize_url is used when authorising the user.